# Comparing the numbers of 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compare

How could I write a function that compares `a` to `b` and then outputs the arrays that are in a but not in b?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,6,80,4,5,6])
b = np.array([1,2,3,70,50])
```

Expected Result

```
[80,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Sets would be more helpful than arrays in this case.

Comment: Convert to sets

Comment: I found the linked duplicate by putting `numpy remove elements from other array` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=numpy+remove+elements+from+other+array). In the future, please try simple searches like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setxor1d.:

```
c = np.setxor1d(a, b)
```